# Progressbar con texto dentro

Tags: javascript, html, progressbar

estoy intentando hacer que funcione un progressbar que he encontrado y que es exactamente lo que necesito. El progressbar que intento usar es de esta [web](https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/), para mas exactos [este](https://jsfiddle.net/72tkyn40/17760/).
Pero por mas quwe intento, no lo logro hacer funcionar, no veo nada del codigo que inserto, y necesito 3 de estas....... Llevo todo el dia con esto y no hay manera.
Alguien me puede ayudar?
Gracias.

Comment: Puedes compartir tu código para observar el error?

Comment: Debes revisar [ask] y modificar tu pregunta en base a esta información para que obtengas buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No has compartido el código, pero supongo que te falta algo para que funcione.

En primer lugar debes llamar al fichero progressbar.js que debes descargar desde [aquí](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/edit/master/dist/progressbar.js) y subirlo a tu servidor, donde tendrás que hacer la llamada al fichero.
Luego ya puedes declarar el contenedor `<div>` donde está tu `#container`. Acto seguido declaramos el `<style>` que queramos, en este caso usaremos el que nos proporciona la demo.

Y finalmente declararemos el `<script>` que recorre el círculo.

```
<!-- Llamamos a la librería JS -->
<script src="progressbar.js"></script>

<!-- Declaramos el contenedor -->
<div id="container"></div>

<!-- Estilos -->
<style>
#container {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
</style>

<!-- Script de progreso -->
<script>
// progressbar.js@1.0.0 version is used
// Docs: http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.0/

var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(container, {
  color: '#aaa',
  // This has to be the same size as the maximum width to
  // prevent clipping
  strokeWidth: 4,
  trailWidth: 1,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  text: {
    autoStyleContainer: false
  },
  from: { color: '#aaa', width: 1 },
  to: { color: '#333', width: 4 },
  // Set default step function for all animate calls
  step: function(state, circle) {
    circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
    circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);

    var value = Math.round(circle.value() * 100);
    if (value === 0) {
      circle.setText('');
    } else {
      circle.setText(value);
    }

  }
});
bar.text.style.fontFamily = '"Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif';
bar.text.style.fontSize = '2rem';

bar.animate(1.0);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
</script>
```

Comment: Vale, el fallo que  tenia era que estaba usando el progressbar.js y el circle.js y me daba fallo tooodo el rato. Muchas gracias.